# CSS only - Breaking rules for UL/LI displayed as table

Tags: html, css, pdf, page-break

**Question:** Are there any specific breaking rules for unordered lists that are displayed as tables?

**Problem:** I can prevent the last row from breaking away from the second last row, but with the same CSS rules I can't prevent the second row from breaking away from the first row.

I have following HTML structure:

```
<ul>
    <li class="wrapperoutside">
        <ul>
            <li class="wrapperinside">
                <p>Heading1</p>
                <p>Heading2</p>
            </li>
            <li class="wrapperinside">
                <p>Part name 1</p>
                <p>Part name 1</p>
            </li>
            <li class="wrapperinside">
                <p>Part name 2</p>
                <p>Part name 2</p>
            </li>
            <li class="wrapperinside">
                <p>Part name 3</p>
                <p>Part name 3</p>
            </li>
            <li class="wrapperinside">
                <p>Part name 4</p>
                <p>Part name 4</p>
            </li>
            <li class="wrapperinside">
                <p>Part name 5</p>
                <p>Part name 5</p>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my CSS to create the table:

```
li.wrapperoutside {
    display:table;
}

li.wrapperoutside li.wrapperinside {
    display: table-row;
}

li.wrapperoutside li.wrapperinside p {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Since this is published as PDF output (using Antenna House as formatter) I have to care about some typographic things, e.g. prevent the last row from breaking away from the second last row. It works with this:

```
li.wrapperoutside li.wrapperinside:last-child {
    page-break-before: avoid!important;
}
```

Things start to get weird with the other way round: Prevent the second row from breaking away from the first row:

```
li.wrapperoutside li.wrapperinside:first-child {
    page-break-after: avoid!important;
}
```

It doesn't work. Instead, **the whole unordered list is not breaking anymore**. 
I tried different selectors:

```
li.wrapperoutside li.wrapperinside:nth-child(2) {
    page-break-before: avoid!important;
}
```

or

```
li.wrapperinside:nth-child(1) + li.wrapperinside:nth-child(2) {
    page-break-after: avoid!important;
}
```

I tried all kinds of selector approaches to use the page-break-rules but it just won't work for the first row. Since the breaking rules are working on the last row with the same CSS rules it's weird to me.

Background about the nested HTML: 
I'm using a content management system and can't influence the HTML classes of UL. I can only influence the classes of LI, this is why I'm using the LI to display the table...

Comment: If it is tabular data, why not use a table?  putting it into a list like you have is semantically incorrect as you have columns of data that don't match up with their headings.  Anyway, I think your problem is that `avoid` only has basic support - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Tabular data deserves a table.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I avoid tables since I organize all data in a content management system. The content is published in different output formats, PDF is one of those. The data is tabular in the PDF, but not always in other output formats. Following the content must be separated from the layout (single source approach). If I start to store the content already in tables in the CMS, I'm not flexible anymore in other output formats. Fair enough: The list construction right now is also not the best solution but at least it's transformable...

Comment: but you're saving the data into the database directly as \<ul>s and \<li>s?

Comment: with the current structure you have a display:block element (the class-less UL) between your  display:table element (.wrapperoutside) and your display:table-row ones (.wrapperinside). Check if setting that UL to display:contents or changing the selector on your display:table declaration to "li.wrapperoutside ul{}" instead of "li.wrapperoutside{}" fixes the issue ;)

Comment: @FacundoCorradini That would be `display:table-row-group`, to emulate the tbody.

Comment: @Facundo Corradini: Thanks for your thoughts. Your ideas led to the solution :)

Comment: @Mr Lister: Thanks alot for your hint with "display:table-row-group" on "li.wrapperoutside ul{}". That did the trick!

Comment: @MrLister well spotted :=) Still, a table-row-group ("tbody") should be optional, specially since we are dealing with presentation and not actual semantics. So changing the `display:table` from the `.wrapperoutside` to the `wrapperoutside ul` should work as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: @FacundoCorradini Good point. Yes, in that case the outer list isn't needed at all!

Comment: @FacundoCorradini, I tried that as well, but it didn't solve the problem with the breaking of the first and the second row - it was like in the beginning that the whole table isn't breaking at all then.

Comment: @Georg The problem is that the `page-break-*` functions inside tables (or css tables) is spotty. I don't think you'll find a good solution to the problem right now.

Comment: Well, glad it worked, despite not being sure why :p

Comment: For the record, AH Formatter is one of the spots where `page-break-*` properties do work.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf65/ahf-css6.html#css21-page-media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS in the question missed the declaration of the unclassified UL between "li.wrapperoutside" and "li.wrapperinside":

```
ul li.wrapperoutside ul {
    display:table-row-group;
}
```

With this additional declaration the generated table breaks as it should break: In case there is no more space in the column/page, the generated table breaks on the other column/page. It does not break between the first and second row and the last and second last row.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` pseudo-classes:

```
li.wrapperinside:first-of-type {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}
li.wrapperinside:last-of-type {
    page-break-before: avoid;
}
```

See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf65/ahf-css6.html#css3-pseudo-clssses, https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#first-of-type-pseudo, and https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#last-of-type-pseudo